# Masonry Leaving Whitespaces/Gaps

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-masonry, masonry

Working with masonry.js, it is being populated by rails but is leaving gaps all over the place, I tried two layouts and the pictures and corresponding codes are below.How may I get rid of the gaps indicated by the red arrows.Research states that it may not pack all the way and I should use packery however I've seen examples of masonry filling entire websites like here [Example](http://www.erikjohanssonphoto.com/work)

Layout 1
[image]

Layout 1 code

HTML

```
<div id="restaurants">

      <%@restaurant.each do |f| %>

          <div class="box">

            <%= image_tag f.thumbnail.url(:medium)%>
          </div>

      <% end %>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('#restaurants').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.box',
       gutter: 0,
       columnWidth: 1



    });
});
```

CSS

```
.box {
  height: 320px;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Layout 2 (which I prefer more)

[image]

All the code remains the same except the css which is just

```
.box { 
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the image height and width height you have provided..trying giving width :100% and height 100% to fit to the box

Comment: @NagaSaiA Thanks, I tried your method but it didn't change the layout

Comment: did you observe any change with widht  and height 100% ?

Comment: @NagaSaiA yes, the images stretched and looked warped, the box also got bigger but there is still the space on the right side seen in layout 1 and layout two image above

Comment: try padding:0px with your existing code

Comment: @NagaSaiA so that kind of worked, on my secondary monitor there is no gap at full window size anymore, when I make the window size smaller the gap appears which means on mobile it would present, on my main monitor it still remains the same, looks like it's not responsive, this is a tough one

Comment: my answer  helped your question :)

Comment: @NagaSaiA the problem still persists however thanks for your time :)

Comment: posting as answer ..can you mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding : 0px will fix your current issue but for window resize image gap , you need to consider other layout elements to make it responsive and make it fit to the box...